# Save buffer from express with GridFS in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, express, typescript, multipartform-data, gridfs

So I'm trying to save a Image file im sending as multipart in my MongoDB via GridFS.
I'm using multer and the memoryStorage option.

```
let upload = multer({ storage:  multer.memoryStorage() }).single('imageFile');
app.use(upload);
```

Inside the route I access the buffer like this:

```
let buffer: Buffer = req.file.buffer;
```

This works fine and I'm struggling with saving this buffer to my MongoDB.

```
let writeStream = this.gfs.createWriteStream({
            mode: 'w',
            filename: 'Image',
            content_type: 'image/png'
        });
streamifier.createReadStream(buffer).pipe(writeStream);
```

This is how I try to save the buffer in my MongoDB.

```
Mongoose: fs.files.ensureIndex([ [ 'filename', 1 ] ], { w: 1 })
Mongoose: fs.chunks.ensureIndex([ [ 'files_id', 1 ], [ 'n', 1 ] ], { w: 1, unique: true })
Mongoose: fs.files.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("597089c973179c0138eef7ae") }, { w: 1, readPreference: 'primary' })
```

This is the log I get from my MongoDB. But nothing is stored in the DB.

Does anyone have a solution? Already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28008731/unable-to-write-buffer-to-mongodb-gridfs) but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the problem was not the code I posted.
It works but be sure that your gfs is loaded with the MongoDB instance and not the connection.